# Rational points on $y^5 = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Doess the above curve have only two rational points namely $(x,y)=(0,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: Please provide more context and show some effort (what have you tried so far? What experience do you have in this subject?)

Comment: As per Faltings theorem there are only finitely many rational points. I don't know if there is an efficient method for finding all of them. The tools are likely very specialized and/or ad hoc. Given all that it is IMHO unreasonable to expect the OP to show much more effort.

Comment: @Issac I didn't mean to offend you... A user names Normal Human has actually set up a bot to say the same as I did, and he has way more rep than I, because what I recommend comes directly from the. SE question guide. It is true that many questions show little effort by the person asking the question, but that does not mean that this is what should be happening... Please consult the guide for asking questions on Math.SE to check me on this. I only recommend context because it allows you to find answers faster... It is hard to know how to help someone if they don't tell you much!

Comment: I think the question about the post by @BrevanEllefsen is quite legitimate.The question is clear, but the techniques involved in answering such questions can vary from elementary to the frontiers of research. Clarity about the level at which you are working may greatly help those who would like to give constructive answers or comments. Your own work or the context in which the question has arisen will help people to give more constructive answers or to identify the particular points or issues you may have missed.

Comment: Your profile shows that you are asking lots of questions about  Diophantine equations with degree greater than 2. As @MarcBennet notes in referring to BrevanEllefsen 's comment, these are usually very deep questions. Do you have a particular source for your questions, or are they random? What skills do you have to think about answering them yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several references on integer (and rational) solutions of the equation
$$
y^n=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{m-1}
$$
for $m>2,\; n>1$, e.g. the article of [Li Yu and Maohua Le](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa73/aa7345.pdf) and the references therein; the article of N. Hirata-Kohno and T.N. Shorey of 1996, "On the equation $(x^m-1)/(x-1)=y^q$ and the references therein, in several articles by Y. Bugeaud, and in many other papers of this kind. I think that if a complete answer is possible, then you will find the answer (and a proof) there in the literature . For $(m,n)=(5,5)$ it is your equation. I believe it is your task now, to go through these many cases which have been treated there.