# On the representation of $\sqrt{\pm p}$ in the integral basis of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, integral-basis

I took another look at my previous question on proving [a certain trigonometric identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3606490/357390) related to the [braced heptagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3954719/357390):
$$\sin\frac\pi7-\sin\frac{2\pi}7-\sin\frac{4\pi}7=-\frac{\sqrt7}2$$
Around the time I posted the first question I was trying to find similar identities for higher primes $p$ in the hope of bracing larger polygons, but without success. When I took the second look it became clear that such identities exist for all odd primes because of [the quadratic subfield embedded in every cyclotomic field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30111/357390) – the roots of unity naturally correspond with the edges of the polygon to be braced.

For example, with $p=11$
$$\frac{\sqrt{-11}-1}2=z+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^9\qquad z=e^{2i\pi/11}$$
and based on this I managed to find a cheap way to remove two degrees of freedom in a braced regular hendecagon using a Moser spindle:

[image]

This leads in turn to an explicit braced regular hendecagon with 41 vertices and **79 edges**, much better than [Khodulyov's 155](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0100.html). ([The proof of rigidity](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/blob/6f58f359299a71d0b766feab73c65c8bcb273ee2/shibuya/brace11gon/brace11gonproof.py) is explained in the docstring of [the function generating this graph](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya/blob/6f58f359299a71d0b766feab73c65c8bcb273ee2/shibuya/bracepoly.py#L76) in Shibuya.)

[image]

---

My question here concerns a pattern I noticed when finding the representations of $\sqrt{\pm p}$ in the integral basis of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$, which is also a $\mathbb Q$-basis for the field (the sign is of course chosen to ensure containment).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sympy import *
x, zt = symbols('x zeta')

for p in (3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53):
    quadratic = x*x-p if p%4 == 1 else x*x+p
    zval = exp(2*pi*I/p)
    expr = x - factor(quadratic, extension=zval).args[1].subs(zval, zt)
    print(f"p = {p}: \sqrt{{{x*x-quadratic}}} = {latex(expr)}\\\\")
```

No matter the $p$ two things seem to always hold:

- The coefficients in front of each $\zeta_p$ are always $2$, except the $\zeta^0$ coefficient which is $1$.
- If $p\equiv1\bmod4$ (so that we have $\sqrt{+p}$) the $\zeta$-powers occur in pairs $\zeta^i,\zeta^{-i}$. If $p\equiv3\bmod4$ (so that we have $\sqrt{-p}$) exactly one of $\zeta^i,\zeta^{-i}$ occurs for $1\le i\le\frac{p-1}2$.

To illustrate:
$$p = 47: \sqrt{-47} = 2 \zeta^{21} + 2 \zeta^{18} + 2 \zeta^{17} + 2 \zeta^{16} + 2 \zeta^{14} + 2 \zeta^{12} + 2 \zeta^{9} + 2 \zeta^{8} + 2 \zeta^{7} + 2 \zeta^{6} + 2 \zeta^{4} + 2 \zeta^{3} + 2 \zeta^{2} + 2 \zeta + 1 + \frac{2}{\zeta^{5}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{10}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{11}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{13}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{15}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{19}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{20}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{22}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{23}}\\
p = 53: \sqrt{53} = 2 \zeta^{26} + 2 \zeta^{23} + 2 \zeta^{22} + 2 \zeta^{21} + 2 \zeta^{20} + 2 \zeta^{19} + 2 \zeta^{18} + 2 \zeta^{14} + 2 \zeta^{12} + 2 \zeta^{8} + 2 \zeta^{5} + 2 \zeta^{3} + 2 \zeta^{2} + 1 + \frac{2}{\zeta^{2}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{3}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{5}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{8}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{12}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{14}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{18}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{19}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{20}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{21}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{22}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{23}} + \frac{2}{\zeta^{26}}$$

> Are the two observations above true for all odd primes $p$? If so, how can they be proved?

Comment: see http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf  and  early pages in Reuschle  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tafeln_complexer_Primzahlen/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: in Reuschle, for each prime, the quadratic is usually on the last page. 7: page 7....  11 p 10.......13 p 16.........17 p20.......19 p 27......23 p31.....29 p37...31 p46...........37 p55........41 p62..........43 p71.......47 p74...........53 page 81  The exponent 2 is hard to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of a non-obvious property of Gauss sums, namely, that for $\chi$ the non-trivial $\{\pm 1\}$-valued character on $\mathbb Z/p^\times$, for odd $p$,
$$
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \chi(k)e^{2\pi ik/p}\Big)^2\;=\; (-1)^{{p-1\over 2}}\cdot p
$$
Also, by a standard cancellation lemma, $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi ik/p}=0$. Adding these two identities together gives these identities. Yes, as in comments, this sort of thing has been know since Gauss, but/and was significantly harder to express in those days.